# git-lfs on WSL blocked by Avast Free Antivirus

Tags: windows-10, git, anti-virus, windows-subsystem-for-linux, avast

The following problem suddenly turned up on my Windows 10 Laptop: I have been using the Windows Subsystem for Linux for years, and I've used git-lfs (git large file storage) on the WSL for several months now. However, starting today, when I try to do a git pull on the WSL with Avast (free version) activated on Windows 10, Avast kicks in and tells me that git-lfs is infected with `ELF:Agent-AJO [Trj]` after which git-lfs becomes unusable (even when deactivating Avast). With Avast deactivated, I succeeded in reinstalling git-lfs (with considerable problems, see below). However, I now have to deactivate Avast every time I run git-lfs on the WSL (I didn't manage to add an exception), which is quite annoying (and I do not think it likely that the threat perceived by Avast is real). Does anyone have any advice on what to do?

That is, **my question is**: how can I keep using git-lfs on WSL without disabling Avast every time? (e.g. how could I add an appropriate exception in the Avast settings)

**More Details**: (I can provide more information if required)

[image]

This is the Avast log (in German, the English Avast equivalent seems to be "Threat Secured; Moved ... to Virus Chest because it was infected with ..." / for the 2nd from the top: "Threat Secured; Safely aborted connection on ... because it was infected with ..."). The oldest entry (12:10) was when I first got the problem. The entry at 12:13 was a retry (without reinstall of git-lfs). The entry at 12:17 was when I downloaded the newest git-lfs version from https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/releases/tag/v2.11.0 - I had to deactivate Avast to complete the download (the SHA256 checksum was valid). The entry at 12:48 was created after the reinstall of git-lfs.

**More Details on reinstalling git-lfs**:
This is maybe off-topic, but I also had considerable problems reinstalling git-lfs. On the WSL, I get

[image]

and in Windows explorer (run with administrator rights), when I try to delete the file,

[image]

(English equivalent: "File Access Denied. You need permission to perform this action. You require permission from 'Administrator of this computer' to make changes to this file.") The only thing which finally worked was copying the newly downloaded git-lfs file in Windows explorer to the destination folder - the old file was overwritten without complaint.

**Edit**:
After I came across VirusTotal in some of the related questions, I submitted the git-lfs executable to their site. Only Avast and AVG (which are basically the same, as far as I understand) detect an infection. See https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/f48f45cf8ca600cdde4a8f27b16faf761e2ab944eaf1b0d9a38f66e9979b7df0/detection or screenshot below

[image]

Comment: If the file does not contain sensible info just upload it to Avast as False-Positive: https://www.avast.com/en-us/false-positive-file-form.php

Comment: Avast already offered that to me in the pop-up notifying me about the blocked program. I followed the steps to flag it as false positive, and I've now also resubmitted it on the site you've linked to. So I guess I have to hope Avast will fix the issue...?

Comment: I am confused by this question.  This seems like a question about a false positive on a file that is trusted. In fact, I don’t see a question, that can be answered.

Comment: The question was how I could keep using git-lfs on the WSL without deactivating Avast on Windows 10. Submitting the file as a false positive will hopefully resolve the issue in the future, but I was hoping for a more immediate solution, also see my answer below.

Comment: When I got the Avast pop-up about the blocked git-lfs, it offered me to set an exception for it (which I did), but Avast continued to kick in, anyway. Therefore, I was unsure how to tell Avast to ignore this file (immediately) - I wasn't aware of where the WSL file system is located on disk (I thought the only way to access it in Windows was via the "network", see my last screenshot above)

Comment: Avast and AVG don't seem to understand Go binaries and flag them as malware.  In general, you are better off using Windows Defender than any other antivirus solution; it does not have this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More or less by accident, I think I found the file path I have to add to the exceptions in Avast - at least, the last git pull on WSL worked fine for me (with Avast activated).

```
C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_...\LocalState\rootfs\...
```

where you can replace the last `...` with the WSL path to a file you want to add to exceptions, e.g. `usr\local\bin`.

---

I also got this e-mail from Avast:

> Hello,
>
> Thank you for reporting this false positive.  Our virus specialists
>   have now cleared its reputation in our database. With URLs this change
>   should be instant, but it might take up to 24 hours with files. For
>   future reference you might also find the following article to be
>   useful: [Avast Clean Guidelines](https://support.avast.com/en-us/article/228/).
>
> Best regards,
>
> Avast Customer Care

and it looks like the file is indeed not identified as a threat anymore.